# MATLAB how to map the received point to one of the constellation points

Tags: matlab, communication, detection, modulation

I'm trying to design a new modulator / demodulator.

I've designed the constellation set and mapped them to bits using a gray mapping, Added some AWGN noise to the signal and now I'm trying to demodulate.

Lets say I have the following points in my constellation:
{ (-1,1), (-1,-1), (1,1), (1,-1) } 
And I got the point (0.5,0.5) after the AWGN. 
Now I need to map it to the closest constellation point, in this case (1,1), and then output the corresponding bits.

What I'm looking for is an automated setup to map the points received to the closest constellation points.

Can anyone suggest a way to do it or a function to use?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried something yet ?

Comment: @Ratbert I've tried doing the demodulation for a 4QAM modulation, by doing the minimum distance algorithm myself. But Now I'm working with constellation sets with size 64 and above, which made me look for a pre defined function for that

Answer (score -1):

hassoun 5las min l nested loops byemshe l7al :P